# Why does this QUnit RegExp test fail?

Tags: javascript, regex, unit-testing, qunit

I'm messing around with QUnit and there is one thing I stumbled upon.

I tried this simple test on Chrome:

```
deepEqual(new RegExp(), /(?:)/);
```

I assumed it would pass, since `new RegExp()` returns `/(?:)/` in the Developer Console. It seems not possible to 'just' do `new RegExp() === /(?:)/` for `RegExp`s, but the `toString()` function of both return the same and *are* equal.

I thought that the literal/non-literal notation would make a difference, but that cannot be the case since this test passes:

```
deepEqual(new RegExp(" "), / /);
```

So, from the following tests the first fails:

```
test("test", function() {
    deepEqual(new RegExp(), /(?:)/); // fail
    deepEqual(new RegExp(" "), / /); // pass
    equal(new RegExp().toString(), /(?:)/.toString()); // pass
});
```

Therefore, could someone point me in the right direction as to why the first test fails please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: The value of the `source` property is different for the regex-literal `/(?:)/` and the object you get from `new RegExp()`. In the case of the literal it's `/(?:)/`, whereas in the case of the object, it's an empty string. When you do `/ /` and `new RegExp(" ")`, the value of the `source` property is the same (both are strings with one space-character).

**Long answer**: If you look at Qunit's source, you'll see this bit of code:

```
"regexp": function (b, a) {
    return QUnit.objectType(b) === "regexp" &&
        a.source === b.source && // the regex itself
        a.global === b.global && // and its modifers (gmi) ...
        a.ignoreCase === b.ignoreCase &&
        a.multiline === b.multiline;
};
```

You can see how the source parameter is different using this code (it simply outputs the properties of each regex argument and tests them for equality):

```
function eq(x, y) {
   console.log("x.source:", "'" + x.source + "'", "y.source:", "'" + y.source + "'", "===:", x.source === y.source);
   console.log("x.global:", x.global, "y.global:", y.global, "===:", x.global === y.global);
   console.log("x.ignoreCase:", x.ignoreCase, "y.ignoreCase:", y.ignoreCase, "===:", x.ignoreCase === y.ignoreCase);
   console.log("x.multiline:", x.multiline, "y.multiline:", y.multiline, "===:", x.multiline === y.multiline);
}
```

When you call this with `eq(/(?:)/, new RegExp());`, you get:

```
x.source: '(?:)' y.source: '' ===: false
x.global: false y.global: false ===: true
x.ignoreCase: false y.ignoreCase: false ===: true
x.multiline: false y.multiline: false ===: true
```

Whereas when you call it with `eq(/ /, new RegExp(" "));` you get:

```
x.source: ' ' y.source: ' ' ===: true
x.global: false y.global: false ===: true
x.ignoreCase: false y.ignoreCase: false ===: true
x.multiline: false y.multiline: false ===: true
```